# Can't send JSON request from php?

Tags: php, json, curl

I tried to send JSON request from me server like this :

```
public function subscribe() {
    $arrData = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'merchant_reference' => $merchant_reference
    );

    $ch = curl_init(env('MY_API'));
    # Setup request to send json via POST.
    $data = json_encode($arrData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    # Return response instead of printing.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    # Send request.
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

And when I call this function from the browser I get error `415`,
But when I call it from [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) it work's fine and return the right response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is `$arrData` defined?

Comment: add `'Accept: application/json',` in header and test, and `# Setup request to send json via POST.` how?

Comment: `$arrData` does not exist in the `subscribe` method's scope.

Comment: I added `Accept: application/json` header but still getting the same error `415 Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: have you tried to convert post json to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));` ?

Comment: Try to change `array('Content-Type:application/json')` to `array('Content-Type: application/json')` - note the space between header name and value.

Comment: @ravisachaniya: `http_build_query` not required because OP using json

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Try adding the following header too: `Accept: application/json`

Comment: When i added this header it's start to give me the same error in postman too

Comment: well, where is `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL );` ?????

Comment: I use $ch = curl_init(env('MY_API'));

Comment: and its working fine right? last question, make sure you are using this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json' 
));`

Comment: Still the same error :(

Comment: **If a server is not able to process the Content-Type of the request, it will return a 415 HTTP error.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124288/discussion-between-mohammad-al-raoosh-and-devpro).

Comment: Please tell us which web server you use and how you call the php code from the html page.

Comment: nginx server, and i call my php code with `<a href="/subscribe">subscribe</a>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is like what @devpro said in my local server, it seems that there is some configuration that i need to change in my local server to allow sending JSON request

Answer (score 0):

As I see you don't pass $arrData to the subscribe function

Comment: The $arrData is inside subscribe function

Answer (score 0):

You forgot set option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Also always can debug query with any own TCP listener, like a `netcat`

UPD:
After send request, check response status code:

```
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: @MohammadAL-Raoosh, your code, not consider lack of `CURLOPT_URL` option, sucessful run.
So, maybe 415 not related with this query?